# Why does a negative number converted to size_t become a huge number in C?

Tags: c, unsigned, size-t

When I build a simple program that lets the user enter a number
(`size_t num`), I don't understand why input of a negative number
results in a huge number instead of an error message.

```
size_t num;
printf("enter num:");
scanf("%lu",&num);
printf("%lu",num);
```

Comment: As side note: `size_t` is not made to store and representing negative values. If you want to represent negative values too, use `ssize_t` and the `%zd` conversion specifier in the call to `scanf()` and `printf()`.

Answer (score 4):

The `%u` format specifier will actually accept a string representation of a signed integer, with the result being converted to an unsigned integer.

Section 7.21.6.2p12 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the `fscanf` function (and by extension, `scanf`) says the following about the `u` conversion specifier:

> **Matches  an  optionally  signed  decimal  integer**, whose  format  is 
>   the  same  as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul`
>   function with the value 10 for  the `base` argument.   The 
>   corresponding  argument  shall  be  a  pointer  to unsigned integer.

The conversion from signed to unsigned happens by logically adding the maximum value the unsigned type can hold +1 to the numeric value of the signed type until the result is in the range of the unsigned type.  Note that this happen regardless of the underlying representation of the relevant integer types.

So for example, assuming `size_t` is a 64 bit type, the largest value it can hold is 18446744073709551615.  So if you input -1 then 18446744073709551616 is added to -1 to give you 18446744073709551615 which is the result.

This conversion is documented in section 6.3.1.3:

> *1* When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new
>   type, it is unchanged.
>
> *2* **Otherwise,  if  the  new  type  is  unsigned,  the  value  is  converted  by  repeatedly  adding  or subtracting  one  more  than 
>   the  maximum  value  that  can  be  represented  in  the  new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.**
>
> *3* Otherwise,  the  new  type  is  signed  and  the  value  cannot  be  represented  in  it;  either  the result is implementation-defined
>   or an implementation-defined signal is raised.

Answer (score 2):

The specification for the `u` conversion in C 2018 7.21.6.2 12 says:

> Matches an optionally signed decimal integer, whose format is the same as expected for the subject sequence of the `strtoul` function with the value 10 for the `base` argument. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to unsigned integer.

(The `l` modifier further qualifies it to be an `unsigned long`.)

Thus, a sign is permitted when scanning with `%lu`. Per paragraph 10:

> … the input item … is converted to a type appropriate to the conversion specifier.

Conversions to `unsigned long` wrap modulo `ULONG_MAX`+1, so small negative values are converted to large positive values.

Incidentally, to scan a numeral into a `size_t`, you should use `%zu`. The `z` modifier is specifically for `size_t`.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` are `unsigned`. In the binary representation of a number, the first bit represent the sign (for `signed int`), so when the computer reads the number thinking it is a `size_t`, it will not interpret the first bit as a negative sign but as a part of the number. Since it is the first bit, i.e. the highest power of two, you get a large number. You can read more about binary representation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_number

There is no error because the the computer just reads the bits indicated in memory by the variable, and this represents a valid `size_t`, so there is now way for the computer to know that this is wrong.

Comment: Yes obviously, but this does not explain why ``scanf()`` does not fail. ``"%lu"`` is different from ``"%ld"``, so, why does ``scanf()`` accept a negative number (and returns ``1``, and stores the value in ``num``) ? (by the way the problem is the same with ``signed/unsigned int`` and ``"%d"``/``"%u"``)

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type. It is not necessarily `unsigned int`.

Comment: @prog-fh `scanf()` doesn't have any way to tell that the format string doesn't actually match the parameter list, thats the job of the developer

Comment: @FelixG no! here ``scanf()`` knows the format string **and** the input. This is not a bad cast problem.

Comment: @prog-fh `scanf()` *never* knows anything about its parameters outside of what was specified in the format string. The compiler can do a cross-check (if it's a decent compiler and the corresponding warnings are enabled), but the scanf() function itself can't.

Comment: @FelixG Sorry for the confusion but I'm afraid we are not on the same subject here. I agree with you in general about the match between the pointer type (parameter) and the format string that cannot be strictly checked, but I think the problem here is about a mismatch between the format string and the actual input (characters from stdin). The two other answers explain this, finally ;^)